# How to convert this to a list or numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
cm = [[406402  30      0      0     11      6      0      0      0      0
     200      0      0      0      0]
 [    89    269      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
       0      0      0      0      0]
 [     9      0  25854      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
       0      0      0      0      0]
 [     5      0      0   2050      2      0      0      0      0      0
       0      0      0      0      0]
 [    64      0      1      6  34497      0      0      0      0      0
       1      0      0      0      0]
 [     3      0      0      0      0    982      5      0      0      0
       0      0      0      0      0]
 [     4      0      0      0      0      3   1072      0      0      0
       0      0      1      0      0]
 [     0      0      0      0      0      0      0   1132      0      0
       0      0      0      0      0]
 [     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
       0      0      0      0      0]
 [     2      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      5
       0      0      0      0      0]
 [   100      0      0      0      5      0      0      0      0      0
   11298      0      0      0      2]
 [     6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
       0    628      0      0      0]
 [     8      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
       0      0    235      0     38]
 [     3      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
       0      0      1      0      0]
 [     1      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0
       0      0     67      0     47]]
```

I got this output of shape (15,15) from sklearn's confusion matrix but I get an invalid syntax error when I try to convert it into an np array. How can I do that? Need commas between elements of each array and between different arrays

Comment: If you're copy and pasting the output of `sklearn` confusion matrix to somewhere else, you shouldn't cause that's what's causing this error. What you should do is save the output of it and then do `np.array(output)`

Comment: That's the print display of a `numpy` array; it isn't meant to be machine readable.  The display of a list can be `eval`, but this requires some editing first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly convert this to np.array. You need add commas between elements and rows. For example:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```